# diagonal var-cov matrix for random slope in lme4

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, covariance-matrix

I am fitting a mixed effect model with a random slope on a factor with 6 levels using the function `lmer()`.

```
lmer(cc_marg ~ mPair + (0 + mPair | ratID), data = dat, REML = FALSE, 
     na.action = na.omit, control = lCtr)
```

I would like to simplify the variance-covariance matrix of the random effect by specifying that the 6 levels of the factor `mPair` are uncorrelated. In other words, I would like to specify a diagonal var-cov matrix. How can I do that using `lmer()`?

I know it would be easier to use `lme()` from the `nlme` package, as I would have access to `pdClass`. However, that package has issues at estimating the denominator DF for random slope models, and therefore, I would prefer to use the `lme4` package. Thanks!

Comment: I think you're almost there, you'd need (1 | ratID) + (0 + mPair | ratID) as per this answer [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86958/variance-covariance-structure-for-random-effects-in-lme4]