# Can we estimate independent parameters when $p > n$?

Tags: regularization, independence, ridge-regression

I am using a ridge regression method to estimate the effect of SNPs (*p* = 10000) as random effect for a population of *n*=2000 individuals.

I know that when we estimate fixed effects, the number of independent variables is going to be determined by the *n*, it means that if we have an *n* = 2000, the maximum number of independent vectors to estimate will be 2000. But what happen when *p* variables are treated as random effect?

I come from the biology, so please let me know if any further explanation of my question is needed.

Comment: I would guess it depends on the particulars of your software. but the number of variables will stay at p=10000.  If say you had 10,000 variables that were exactly the same, then the ridge regression solution would be to use the same coefficient for each (ie 1/10,000 of coefficient using single variable)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Can you explain a bit in what way do you think it would depend on the software?

Comment: you could get errors - lack of convergence? etc depending on what variance-covariance structure you impose/is default.. see eg https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86958/variance-covariance-structure-for-random-effects-in-lme4